# Merge rows with same date and add counter column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple DataFrame that looks like this:

```
               date
0   2018-08-28 13:13:37
1   2018-08-28 13:43:31
2   2018-08-28 15:23:25
3   2018-08-28 15:23:30
4   2018-08-28 15:23:33
5   2018-08-28 15:23:34
...
790 2018-09-04 10:45:38
791 2018-09-04 10:45:38
792 2018-09-04 11:13:16
793 2018-09-04 12:12:09
794 2018-09-04 14:01:54
```

I want to group all rows with same date (hour, minute and seconds is not important) and create a new column with the sum (number of merged rows with same date).

The output I'm trying to work out is:

```
          date         sum
0   2018-08-28         6
1   2018-08-29         100
2   2018-08-30         100
3   2018-08-31         100
4   2018-09-01         100
5   2018-09-02         100
6   2018-09-03         100
7   2018-09-04         100
```

I've tried to play around with the [groupby function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) but I'm not able to get the correct output

Comment: Just because the docs are so close to your question wording. [`pd.Series.dt.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) "
The time component of the date-time is converted to midnight i.e. 00:00:00. This is useful in cases, when the time does not matter." Basically the same as using `.dt.date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date).size().rename(columns={'size':'sum'})
```

This method assumes that the `Series` 'date' is already dtype `datetime`.

You can either set this if creating the DataFrame with `pd.read_csv` passing the argument "`parse_dates=['date']`" or by running:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Using `value_counts` with the `dt.date` accessor:

```
df['date'].dt.date.value_counts()
```

Demonstration on your sample data:

```
df['date'].dt.date.value_counts().rename('sum').to_frame()
```

```
            sum
2018-08-28    6
2018-09-04    5
```